# How to work with a custom joint states topic which involves a robot namespace?

Tags: moveit, robotic-arm, c++, ros-noetic, move-group

I am working with a robotic arm in simulation. I am using ros-noetic, gazebo and moveit for this purpose. I am using `/robot_namespace` as robot namespace, because of which robot joints data are being published on `/robot_namespace/joint_states` topic, in place of `/joint_states`.

I am trying to run below c++ code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h>

class MyRobot{
    public:
        explicit MyRobot(ros::NodeHandle nh);
        ~MyRobot();
    private:
        ros::NodeHandle nh_;
        const std::string ARM_PLANNING_GROUP = "arm_manipulator";
        moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface arm_move_group;
        const robot_state::JointModelGroup *arm_joint_model_group;
};   
MyRobot::MyRobot(ros::NodeHandle nh)
  : nh_(nh),
    arm_move_group(ARM_PLANNING_GROUP){
      arm_joint_model_group = arm_move_group.getCurrentState()->getJointModelGroup(ARM_PLANNING_GROUP);
    }
MyRobot::~MyRobot(){}
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
  spinner.start();
  MyRobot myRobot(nh);
  return 0;
}
```

but getting below error:

```
[ INFO] [1589572504.193567368, 922.494000000]: Didn't received robot state (joint angles) with recent timestamp within 1 seconds.Check clock synchronization if your are running ROS across multiple machines!
[ERROR] [1589572504.193719017, 922.494000000]: Failed to fetch current robot state
```

After doing some research, I found that `arm_move_group` uses default `/joint_states` topic, which is mapped to `/robot_namespace/joint_states` in my case via `<remap from="joint_states" to="/robot_namespace/joint_states"/>`

I have already tried some of the solution available online:

1. Passing `joint_states:=/robot_namespace/joint_states` as argument to `move_group` node inside `move_group.launch` file.

   `<node name="move_group" args="joint_states:=/robot_namespace/joint_states $(arg command_args)" ...>`
2. Passing `<param name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>` to `move_group`, `robot_state_publisher` and `rviz` nodes.

But none of the solutions seem to be working in my case.

I would really appreciate some help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like there is a `joint_state_topic` ros param in https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aros-planning%2Fmoveit+joint_state_topic&type=code that you could change.  Also instead of remap `from="joint_states"` try remap `from="/joint_states"` with the leading slash.

Comment: How should I change `joint_state_topic` ? Via launch file(like in move_group.launch) or directly in c++ code? And regarding adding leading slash in `from="joint_states"`, I will do that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think only a moveit test (moveit_cpp) is setting the joint state topic to "/joint_states" instead of "joint_states" (the default according to https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/3d2105584f414f2494eebff17122b398721d9c2a/moveit_ros/planning/planning_scene_monitor/src/planning_scene_monitor.cpp#L111).  If you have the default then the answer below https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/107574/884 applies and my suggested remap won't work.  Alternatively setting joint_state_topic param in the launch file should work (though it's hard to say exactly where you set it to be in the right ns).

Comment: remap `from="/joint_states"` is not working either.

Comment: Ok try `roslaunch some_package_name move_group.launch __ns:=/robot_namespace`

Answer (score 0):

> I found that arm_move_group uses default /joint_states topic

A more accurate statement is that `arm_move_group` uses the `joint_states` topic (with no slash) *in the current namespace* of your MyRobot node.

I think the cleanest way to fix this problem is to execute your MyRobot node in the correct namespace. If using a launch file, you do this with the `ns=` attribute of the `<node>` or `<group>` tag.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this a bit more like where should I put ns="" ?

Comment: There is good documentation for the launch file syntax: https://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML Click the link for `<node>`.

Comment: What I meant was "execute your MyRobot node in the correct namespace" Can you please elaborate this a bit more?